# Javascript video pause is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-video

So I'm having a little trouble with videos, i have a website and there i have the same video displayed in 3 different pages. 
The videos are all paused until the user clicks on them to start.
The problem is when, i leave a page and the video is just there even if i have clicked on play or pause or haven't done anything at all, the other two, give me an error saying vid.pause is not a function.

This is the HTML part ->

`<video id="{{vid?.id}}" src={{vid?.video}} onloadedmetadata="this.paused = true; this.currentTime = 1" (click)="playPause(vid)"> </video>`

And the js ->

```
  playPause(vid) {
    var vid = (<HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById(vid.id));
    if (vid.paused == true) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

One thing to notice is:

You are passing the `vid` property to the element and then back to the `.ts`. This is not good practices.

Also, you are using variables inside properties the wrong way.

The best way to do this would be:

> .html file

```
<video #myVideo [id]="vid?.id" [src]="vid?.video" onloadedmetadata="this.paused = true; this.currentTime = 1" (click)="playPause(myVideo)"> </video>
```

> .ts file

```
playPause(vid: HTMLMediaElement) {
    if (vid.paused == true) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 1;
    }
  }
```

---

My guess is you have a difference in your HTML and JS files.

In your HTML file, you have the video id as `vid.id`. 
In your JS file, you are using `getElementById`, passing the id as `vid.video`.

Therefore `var vid` will be `undefined` and `vid.pause()` won't be a function.

You probably have to use `var vid = (<HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById(vid.id));`

Comment: That was my mistake sorry ;), I'm getting it by id, on that page.

Comment: That helped thanks man! But still have some problems, it works in all browsers except on android there only two pages of the three, on where the video is load that video properly. If you got any suggestions i would appreciate it, but Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to help || If the problem is just on one kind of browser, then it's probably a compatibility issue. You can try and find what you're doing here: `http://caniuse.com`. This website displays information about what technology can be used in any kind of browser. || If I can ask you, can you please upvote my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that I tried pausing a jQuery object, but that's not possible. You need to pause a DOM element. So I corrected it by converting my jQuery object to a DOM element.

**BEFORE:**

```
$("#video").pause();
```

**AFTER / SOLVED:**

```
$("#video")[0].pause();
```